# Is there a JavaScript wrapper for the Tumblr API available?

Tags: javascript, api, tumblr

I am looking to use the Tumblr API for integrating blogs into our website. I am looking for a JavaScript wrapper for the API, to help get started.

I do believe I found one a few weeks ago, but at the time I didn't bookmark the page. After looking again yesterday for a few hours and not finding it, I'm wondering if I'm mistaken.

Can anyone confirm if there is a published JavaScript wrapper for the Tumblr API, and if so, pass on the URL?

Comment: I do not know of a Javascript wrapper, but there _is_ a PHP/HTML interface library if you want to take a look. You'd be comparing apples to oranges and I had to add a couple lines of code to actually get it working with the newest Tumblr API, but I suppose it's a start: [link](https://github.com/jacobbudin/tumblroauth)

Comment: Thanks. I've seen the PHP wrapper. I'll try posting on the Tumblr developer forum to see if anyone has done some work in this direction already. Will post back if I get any useful info related to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3393151/4358*
Aparently there is a .js to make an integration, check it out here:
http://www.tumblr.com/developers

Answer (score 0):

The Documentation can be helpful,check this out http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v1