# how to prevent a script from working when another one is working

Tags: javascript, keyboard, conditional-statements

I have this code for tumblr and i would like that when the .html_photoset fonction is happening, the .onkeyup fonction does not happend, because both fonctions use the arrow key !
How can i add an if in the second script to prevent it from happening when the first one is on ?

```
{block:Photoset}
     {block:PermalinkPage} 

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.html_photoset').killPhotoset({
                    photoSize: 500
                });
            });
        </script>               

        <!-- [...] -->

        {block:PermalinkPagination} 

            <div class="permpaginate">

                {block:NextPost}
                    <a href="{NextPost}" id="prevp">Previous Project</a>
                {/block:NextPost}
                {block:PreviousPost}
                    <a href="{PreviousPost}" id="nextp">Next Project</a>
                {/block:PreviousPost}

            </div>

        {/block:PermalinkPagination}

        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                document.onkeyup = function(event) {
                    var e = (!event) ? window.event : event;
                    switch (e.keyCode) {
                        case 37:
                            window.location.href = document.getElementById('prevp').href;
                            break;
                        case 39:
                            window.location.href = document.getElementById('nextp').href;
                            break;
                    }
                };
            };
        </script>

    {/block:PermalinkPage}

{/block:Photoset}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to approach this.

1. You can set a global flag when html_photoset is happening and then in your other onkeyup handler check the global flag and do nothing if html_photoset is active.  When html_photoset goes inactive, you would then clear the flag so your other keyup handler would start working.
2. You could also deinstall the onkeyup handler and reinstall it at appropriate times.
3. You could stop event propagation with `e.stopPropagation()` in the html_photoset handler so that when you've processed the event in html_photoset, it won't propagate up to the document level where your other keyup handler is.

The cleanest is probably option 3.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to get access to the Tumblr Javascript API. Apparently it's available but only if you're logged in:

[Integrating tumblr blog with website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568210/integrating-tumblr-blog-with-website/3393151#3393151)

So I can't access it to get much more detailed unfortunately.

Generally speaking you should also probably be using a library like jquery to abstract your event code, since the event calls you're using here will only work in some browsers. Ideally you'd leverage whatever event library tumblr itself is already using to get this done, in particular because you're going to want to intervene in its onkeydown/onkeypress/onkeyup event depending on how they're tying in.

The strategy is:

1. Determine which event Tumblr is using to respond to this.
2. Remove the event handler
3. Add your own copy of it back in and when the arrow keys are the ones pressed, determine whether to fire your code or Tumblr's based on whatever context you wanted this to vary on (not clear from your question, but it might for example depend on what tag initiated the event/has focus/etc).